# Current flow through inductor (large inductance) in AC circuit

Tags: current, ac, inductance, graph

I fail to understand why does the current flow in one direction only initially at t=0 in an AC circuit.. also when inductance is increased the time take for the current to stabilize and move in equal amplitudes ( negative and positive) is higher than in the case of inductor with lower inductance[image: Graph variation of current through an inductor]

[image]

Comment: The response to the sinusoid applied at t=0 is a transient plus a steady state sinusoid. The transient decays with a time constant of \$\small \tau=\frac{L}{R}=0.1s\$

Comment: The label on your graph indicates that you are looking at the _voltage_ and not the current. Trend the current too and expand out so you can have a closer look at the first ten cycles or so.

Comment: there is an arrow besides the label V1 which indicates it is current and not voltage.. voltage graph shows equal amplitudes for both positive and negative part ... voltage and current graph cannot be plotted simultaneously as voltages in this varies from +311 to - 311 while the current varies from -1 to +1 since the impedance is high

Comment: impedance in this case = 10ohms + j(2*Pie*f*l)

Comment: = 10+j(6.28*50*1) = 10ohms+j314ohms

Comment: @chu its about 0.3s in this case? but ur right as i decrease the resistance it takes more time to decay...

Comment: Time constant is time to 63% of final value, so 0.1s is about right.

Comment: The voltage graph will just be a sine because it's the voltage of the source. The voltage across the resistor or inductor will be exponential + sine, i.e. the same shape as current.

Answer (score 2):

The transient occurs because, when you turn on the signal generator, the inductor's current started at zero when the sine voltage starts at zero.  That's not a normal, pure-AC situation where the inductor's voltage is always 90deg shifted.

Remember:  inductor current in a pure AC circuit should always be at 90deg phase relative to inductor voltage.  For pure AC situations, inductor current and voltage are *never zero at the same time.*  But when you turned on your signal generator, V & I were both zero. That means that you've started out with some sort of DC-based situation, and it has to decay away, until finally the pure-AC signals are left.

Or said another way:  For the pure-AC wave, when the inductor current is zero, what's the inductor voltage at that instant?  To start up in pure-AC mode, a voltage must already be applied at t=0.   To get rid of the transient pulse, you'd have to start up your sine-voltage generator not at phase=0deg, but with a phase shift.  What phase?  It's the phase which gives the proper sig.gen. voltage at the instant that I=0 for the circuit!  :)  Starting up with any other phase ...that would be the same as applying a DC pulse.

In other words, the inductor is seeing the slow-rise of the first half of your initial sine wave as a DC pulse, a big voltage with the wrong current for producing 90deg phase.  This pulse must fade away before the magnitudes and phases will be correct for pure-AC.

Simple version:  remove the 10ohm resistor, then apply a cosine voltage signal (or, a sine signal with 90deg shift either pos or neg phase.)  That hits the inductor with a large initial voltage while its initial current still remains zero.   The transient will be gone.  Why?

Comment: thx for clearing the doubts... one more thing i would like to add the time taken for transient decay is 5 times the time contant ie 5*l/r if there is a 0 degree phase between current and voltage